# Dimensions of A Subspace of ℝ^n

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an **n x n** matrix **A**. Show that there exist scalars **c<sub>0</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, ... ,c<sub>n</sub>** (not all zero) such that the matrix **A = c<sub>0</sub>I<sub>n</sub> + c<sub>1</sub>A + c<sub>2</sub>A<sup>2</sup> + ... + c<sub>n</sub>A<sup>n</sup>** is non-invertible. (Hint: pick an arbitrary nonzero vector **v̅ in ℝ<sup>n</sup>**. Then the **n+1** vectors **v̅, Av̅, A<sup>2</sup>v̅ , A<sup>n</sup>v̅**  will be linearly dependent).

I am not sure how to prove this. Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. It is encouraged to learn LaTeX typesetting of math formulae. Other than that it is also encouraged to try and show any effort one has tried to find an answer to the question. Especially if it looks like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the hint provided. For $v \in \mathbb R$ not vanishing, the family of vectors $(v, Av, \dots , A^n v)$ is a family of $n+1$ vectors not all vanishing in a vector space of dimension $n$. Hence it is a dependent family and it exist $n+1$ reals $c_0, \dots, c_n$ not all vanishing such that $$c_0 v +c_1 Av +\dots +c_n A^n v=(c_0 I_n + c_1 A + \dots + c_n A^n)v=0$$

Hence the kernel of the matrix $c_0 I_n + \dots + c_n A^n$ is not the null space which proves that this matrix is not invertible.